# Jquery mouse move to android touch move

Tags: android, mobile

I am using jquery mouse move function. and how i change that method or functionality for Android?

Please go through the code...

```
function init(){
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();            
        draw = false;                       
         $(document).mousedown(function(){draw=true;}); 
         $(document).mouseup(function(){draw=false;});  
         $(document).mousemove(function(e) {       
        if(draw==true){
            mx = e.pageX;
            my = e.pageY;
        console.log(mx + "***" + my)        
        });         
    }
```

This is working fine in web browser. When i compile this by using phonegap through eclipse, it  will not working in emulator.

So, What i missed, or what i need to do to convert mouse move event to touch move event for mobile.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the jQuery Touch Punch includes.

See the reference here: [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply. If possible can you please provide some example code. Based on that above function init().

Comment: That's the beauty of it, all you need to do is include the Touch Punch after your jQuery UI includes.  That's it!  It overrides some of the mouse events to map them to touch events.